# Confusion about proper usage of dereference in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, performance

I noticed the other day that - while altering values in a hash - that when you dereference a hash in Perl, you actually are making a copy of that hash.  To confirm I wrote this quick little script:

```
#! perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %h = ();
my $hRef = \%h;
my %h2 = %{$hRef};
my $h2Ref = \%h2;

if($hRef eq $h2Ref) {
  print "\n\tThey're the same $hRef $h2Ref";
}
else {
  print "\n\tThey're NOT the same $hRef $h2Ref";
}
print "\n\n";
```

The output:

```
    They're NOT the same HASH(0x10ff6848) HASH(0x10fede18)
```

This leads me to realize that there could be spots in some of my scripts where they aren't behaving as expected.  Why is it even like this in the first place?  If you're passing or returning a hash, it would be more natural to assume that dereferencing the hash would allow me to alter the values of the hash being dereferenced.  Instead I'm just making copies all over the place without any real need/reason to beyond making syntax a little more obvious.

I realize the fact that I hadn't even noticed this until now shows its probably not that big of a deal (in terms of the need to go fix in all of my scripts - but important going forward).  I think its going to be pretty rare to see noticeable performance differences out of this, but that doesn't alter the fact that I'm still confused.

Is this by design in perl?  Is there some explicit reason I don't know about for this; or is this just known and you - as the programmer - expected to know and write scripts accordingly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a copy of the hash to work with in this line:

```
my %h2 = %{$hRef};
```

And that is understandable, since many posts here on SO use that idiom to make a local name for a hash, without explaining that it is actually making a copy.

In Perl, a hash is a plural value, just like an array.  This means that in list context (such as you get when assigning to a hash) the aggregate is taken apart into a list of its contents.  This list of pairs is then assembled into a new hash as shown.

What you want to do is work with the reference directly.

```
for (keys %$hRef) {...}
for (values %$href) {...}

my $x = $href->{some_key};
# or
my $x = $$href{some_key};

$$href{new_key} = 'new_value';
```

When working with a normal hash, you have the sigil which is either a `%` when talking about the entire hash, a `$` when talking about a single element, and `@` when talking about a slice.  Each of these sigils is then followed by an identifier.

```
 %hash          # whole hash
 $hash{key}     # element
 @hash{qw(a b)} # slice
```

To work with a reference named `$href` simply replace the string `hash` in the above code with `$href`.  In other words, `$href` is the complete name of the identifier:

```
%$href          # whole hash
$$href{key}     # element
@$href{qw(a b)} # slice
```

Each of these could be written in a more verbose form as:

```
%{$href}
${$href}{key}
@{$href}{qw(a b)}
```

Which is again a substitution of the string `'$href'` for `'hash'` as the name of the identifier.

```
%{hash}
${hash}{key}
@{hash}{qw(a b)}
```

You can also use a dereferencing arrow when working with an element:

```
$hash->{key}  # exactly the same as $$hash{key}
```

But I prefer the doubled sigil syntax since it is similar to the whole aggregate and slice syntax, as well as the normal non-reference syntax.

So to sum up, any time you write something like this:

```
my @array = @$array_ref;
my %hash  = %$hash_ref;
```

You will be making a copy of the first level of each aggregate.  When using the dereferencing syntax directly, you will be working on the actual values, and not a copy.

---

If you want a REAL local name for a hash, but want to work on the same hash, you can use the `local` keyword to create an alias.

```
 sub some_sub {
    my $hash_ref = shift;
    our %hash; # declare a lexical name for the global %{__PACKAGE__::hash}
    local *hash = \%$hash_ref;
        # install the hash ref into the glob
        # the `\%` bit ensures we have a hash ref

    # use %hash here, all changes will be made to $hash_ref

 }  # local unwinds here, restoring the global to its previous value if any
```

That is the pure Perl way of aliasing.  If you want to use a `my` variable to hold the alias, you can use the module `Data::Alias`

Comment: Very good explanation - thank you.  I do have a question about the comment `# local unwinds here, restoring the global to its previous value if any`.  So what you're saying here is that if there is another `our %hash;` declared somewhere else, upon entry to `some_sub` it's value is changed, and it is reverted upon exit of `some_sub`?  If this is the case, is it possible to have threading issues where - for example - `our %hash` is created in `some_sub` but referenced in `some_other_sub` concurrently which would create unexpected side-effects?

Comment: There are two things going on.  The first is the `our %hash` line declares that the identifier `%hash` will be an alias for `%package::hash` inside the subroutine (this is just syntactic sugar to prevent writing the package name each time).  The second is that the `local` keyword creates a new dynamic scope, in which the global `%package::hash` variable has a new value.  This scope will be unwound as soon as the subroutine returns (in any way), however, any subroutines that are called from within that scope will have access to the variable (since it is a global after all). Continued...

Comment: Since the `%package::hash` variable is global, it is up to you to ensure that no other subroutines are using it.  `local` provides some protection in this regard, since it creates a new variable for the subroutine.  So presumably, `%package::hash` will be undefined before the subroutine call, and will again be undefined at the end.  So even if another subroutine is doing the same thing (localizing) with the same variable, they will not collide.  The only time you will have an issue is if the variable has a global value outside of the subroutines (since that value will be masked by the local).

Comment: As far as threading goes, in Perl all variables are not shared by default, so each thread will have its own set of independent global variables.  If you did something crazy like sharing the variable across the threads with `threads::shared` and then started localizing it, there might be issues, so don't do that.

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing the actions of dereferencing, which does not inherently create a copy, and using a hash in list context and assigning that list, which does.  `$hashref->{'a'}` is a dereference, but most certainly does affect the original hash.  This is true for `$#$arrayref` or `values(%$hashref)` also.

Without the assignment, just the list context `%$hashref` is a mixed beast; the resulting list contains copies of the hash keys but aliases to the actual hash values.  You can see this in action:

```
$ perl -wle'$x={"a".."f"}; for (%$x) { $_=chr(ord($_)+10) }; print %$x'
epcnal
```

vs.

```
$ perl -wle'$x={"a".."f"}; %y=%$x; for (%y) { $_=chr(ord($_)+10) }; print %$x; print %y'
efcdab
epcnal
```

but `%$hashref` isn't acting any differently than `%hash` here.

Answer (score 5):

No, dereferencing does not create a copy of the referent. It's `my` that creates a new variable.

```
$ perl -E'
   my %h1; my $h1 = \%h1;
   my %h2; my $h2 = \%h2;
   say $h1;
   say $h2;
   say $h1 == $h2 ?1:0;
'
HASH(0x83b62e0)
HASH(0x83b6340)
0

$ perl -E'
   my %h;
   my $h1 = \%h;
   my $h2 = \%h;
   say $h1;
   say $h2;
   say $h1 == $h2 ?1:0;
'
HASH(0x9eae2d8)
HASH(0x9eae2d8)
1
```

No, `$#{$someArrayHashRef}` does not create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

If perl did what you suggest, then variables would get aliased very easily, which would be far more confusing.  As it is, you can alias variables with globbing, but you need to do so explicitly.