# Can I pass mix type of optional arguments to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

I am trying to pass a hash and optional list of variables to a subroutine in hash but its not working. Could you please correct below sample code to help me with the approach?

My sample code looks like

```
#!/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %h1 = ( a=> 2, b=>3);
sub sum {
   my $var1=shift;
   my $var2=shift;

   my %hash1=@_;
   #my($a,$b)=@_;
   my $i=0;
   foreach my $val (keys %hash1) {
        $i=$i+$hash1{$val};
   }
   if ( not defined $var2 ) {
        return ($i+$var1);
   } else {
        return ($i+$var1+$var2);
   }
}
my $c=sum(3,%h1);
print $c;
```

Comment: General advice: Always `use strict;`. Don't call your variables `$a` or `$b` (they have a special meaning in `sort`). Don't call subroutines with `&`.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481405/how-to-pass-a-hash-by-reference-in-perl

Comment: thanks Melpomene. I have updated the code as per your suggestion. Since it's a just sample code so i didn't care about strict function.

Comment: *Since it's a just sample code so i didn't care about strict function* That's never a good idea :-)

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was looking a way to pass the optional arguments with hashes using perl subroutine. I got it working and here, is my sample code

Comment: post your code in an answer, saying you found how to solve your problem (you could even accept your answer), it will be more readable ;)

Answer (score 4):

You call your subroutine like this:

```
my $c=sum(3,%h1);
```

And inside your subroutine, you access the parameters like this:

```
   my $var1=shift;
   my $var2=shift;

   my %hash1=@_;
```

There seems to be an obvious discrepancy here. You're passing a scalar and a hash to the subroutine, but inside your subroutine, you're expecting **two** scalars and a hash.

So perhaps it will work as you expect it to if you remove the `my $var2 = shift` line.

It's not really clear what your subroutine is meant to do. If you were to explain that, then we could probably be a little more help.

**Update:** You have `Data::Dumper` in your code. Why not use it to try to understand what is going on.

```
print Dumper(\@_), "\n";
my $var1=shift;
my $var2=shift;

my %hash1=@_;
print Dumper($var1, $var2, \%hash1), "\n";
```

I get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          3,
          'b',
          3,
          'a',
          2
        ];

Odd number of elements in hash assignment at test line 11.
$VAR1 = 3;
$VAR2 = 'b';
$VAR3 = {
          '3' => 'a',
          '2' => undef
        };
```

Which shows a couple of interesting things:

- The hash being "unrolled" into a list before being put into `@_`.
- The warning you get when you initialise a hash from a list with an odd number of elements.
- Your `%hash1` variable with incorrect keys and values.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was looking a way to pass the optional arguments with hashes using perl subroutine. I got it working and here, is my sample code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This is how we can pass optional arguments to a subroutine in perl with type mixed

```
#!/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %h1 = ( a=> 2, b=>3); 
sub sum {

   my ($hash1,$var1,$var2)=@_;
   #my($a,$b)=@_;
   my $i=0;
   foreach my $val (keys %{$hash1}) {
   $i=$i+$hash1->{$val};
   }
   if (defined $var2 ) {
    return ($i+$var1+$var2);
   } else {
    return ($i+$var1);
   }
}

my $c=sum(\%h1,3);
print $c;
```

Please correct me if I missed something.

Regards,
Divesh

Comment: So you've learned that a) optional arguments go at the end of the parameter list and b) it's better to pass hashes and arrays to subroutines as references.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;
use feature qw(say);

args_in( 'test', { foo => 'bar' }, ["one", "two", "three"] );

sub args_in {
  my $args_aref = parse_args( @_ );
  say to_json $args_aref;
}

sub parse_args {
  my @ary;
  foreach( @_ ) {
    my %hash;
    if (ref $_) {
      $hash{type} = ref $_;
    } else {
      $hash{type} = 'SCALAR';
    }
    $hash{value} = $_;
    push @ary, \%hash;
  }
  return \@ary;
}
```

Results:

```
[
    {
        "value": "test",
        "type": "SCALAR"
    },
    {
        "value": {
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        "type": "HASH"
    },
    {
        "value": [
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
        ],
        "type": "ARRAY"
    }
]
```